# Why won't my character move? I can't figure out why my Rigidbody 2D won't work

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

I want my character to jump, but I cant figure out why he wont. My code uses forces and Rigidbody2D. I'm new at Unity, and I can't find any answers. Please help?

My code for the physics:

```
var trump;

function Start() {
// Assigns the Rigidbody to a variable
trump = GetComponent(Rigidbody2D);

// Variable Switches:

}
function FixedUpdate() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
        GetComponent.<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2(0,20));
    }

}
```

[image: This is what it looks like. How do I do this?]

Comment: I'd be happy to help but you have to post some code or be more specific.   It could be 1 of 100 things going on.

Comment: I added code. Sorry, I accidentally posted without putting in code by pressing enter.

Comment: Haha, I see your character name is Donald Trump.  What are you up to....

Comment: Im going to make an endless runner, when he jumps over fragments of his unfinished wall. Lol

Comment: That is awesome.  I'll be a beta tester for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 'Is Kinematic' checked on your rigidbody, which means physics won't affect .  Did you have a reason for making it kinematic?

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because the Rigidody2D is marked as kinematic.  Doing so stops all forces from acting upon the gameobject.  You can read more about it here: [Rigidbody.isKinematic](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html)

Comment: Thank you a bunch! I only chose Ageonix because he responded in a comment earlier.